# Rails Routing Error - very confused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So at the moment I am following a Tutorial for a Photoblog for Ruby on Rails (my version is 5.0.1)

And right now I have a constant routing error

My `routes.rb`looks as following, generated by Rails

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


  get 'posts/new'

  get 'posts/create'

end
```

When I execute `rake routes` I get this

```
      Prefix Verb URI Pattern             Controller#Action
   posts_new GET  /posts/new(.:format)    posts#new
posts_create GET  /posts/create(.:format) posts#create
```

What makes me curious is, that when I access `/posts/create` manually, it is no problem at all like it should be. 
But in `/posts/new` I fill out a Form which will be redirected and here is where the error occurs

```
<%= form_tag({:action => :create}, :multipart => true) %> 
<fields to be filled in>
</form>
```

Anybody a clue?

My Routing Error looks like this:

```
No route matches [POST] "/posts/create"
```

Comment: Why don't you follow Rails conventions and use [resource routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) instead defining all paths yourself? Something like `resources :posts, only: [:new, :create]` does exactly what you want. Btw it seems like you are following an outdated tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No route matches [POST] "/posts/create"

Your route for `create` should be of type `post`

Change

```
get 'posts/create'
```

to

```
post 'posts/create'
```

Comment: oh, that's so simple, I was just overseeing this!
Thanks a lot!
Rails is fun but sometimes ... :D

Answer (score 0):

A route is identified by an HTTP verb and a path. Your route is

```
get 'posts/create'
```

- **HTTP verb**: `GET`
- **Path**: `posts/create`

A form by default has a `POST` method (the HTTP verb), so you should change your route from

```
get 'posts/create'
```

to

```
post 'posts/create'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the above answers are right. The question can be closed. An alternative would be to add this to your routes.rb

resources :posts
this will give you all the common rails routes for a scaffold resource.